# Contingency table analysis to rank preferences of birds per feature

Tags: r, categorical-data, multinomial-distribution, contingency-tables, covariance-matrix

I have a dataset that contains observations of objects that female blackbirds carry to their nests. The birds have id tags and the objects are grouped categorically with respect to their `colour`, `size` and `texture`. The code that generates the representative `birds.data` in R is at the bottom.

I first look at the contingency tables per feature to see what specific feature categories a bird is more selective on.

```
# Create Contingency Matrices
col_mat <- as.data.frame.matrix(table(birds.data[, c("id", "colour")]))
size_mat <- as.data.frame.matrix(table(birds.data[, c("id", "size")]))
text_mat <- as.data.frame.matrix(table(birds.data[, c("id", "texture")]))
```

Below is a graphical summary where I `cbind()` all matrices above. I can observe that `bird 1` is pretty indifferent to the colours of objects she collects but highly prefers `small` and `soft` objects.

[image]

I first ran $\chi^2$ independence tests as below to compare whether the colour (or any feature) preferences of a bird is different from the rest.

```
# Run chi^2 independence test for bird1 vs rest in colour dimension
bird_1 <-  col_mat[1,] 
rest <- colSums(col_mat[2:4,])
data_test <- rbind(bird_1,rest ) # column - bind the two
chisq.test(data_test)
```

**Question:** However, I do not know how to rank how relatively selective a bird is when comparing different features.  For instance, for `bird1`, I would report ranked preferences as : `texture` > `size` > `colour`. How can I achieve that? (I guess the context independent keyword here may be: **comparing different multinomial distributions**)

**Attempt:** Thinking I cannot compare $\chi^2$ test results between features, I decided to look at variances. Below I calculate the MLE's per feature for `bird1` and then look at the (co)variances (`getMultinomCov()`) of the estimated multinomial probabilities.

```
# Investigate multinom variances per feature for bird1
cov_col <- getMultinomCov(col_mat[1,])
cov_size <- getMultinomCov(size_mat[1,])
cov_text <- getMultinomCov(text_mat[1,])

# Calculating covariance matrix of multinom dist
getMultinomCov <- function (data) {
  N <- sum(data)
  p_hat <- as.numeric(data / N)
  variance         <-  N*p_hat*(1-p_hat)
  covariance       <- -outer(p_hat, p_hat)*N
  diag(covariance) <-  variance
  return <- covariance
}
```

Would comparing the  `cov_col`, `cov_size` and `cov_text` matrices help in finding the  "preference ranking" that I am after? If so, can you please demonstrate/explain how?

---

```
# Bird Sightings Data Generation
set.seed(2013)
bird1.data <- data.frame( id =  rep(1,200),
                          colour = sample(c("Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green"), 200, replace=T, c(0.25,0.25, 0.25, 0.25)),
                          size = sample(c("Large", "Medium","Small"), 200, replace = T, c(0.1,0.3, 0.6)),
                          texture = sample(c("Hard", "Soft"), 200, replace = T, prob = c(0.1,0.8))
)
bird2.data <- data.frame( id =  rep(2,500),
                          colour = sample(c("Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green"), 500, replace=T, c(0.15,0.45, 0.20, 0.20)),
                          size = sample(c("Large", "Medium","Small"), 500, replace = T, c(0.33,0.33, 0.33)),
                          texture = sample(c("Hard", "Soft"), 500, replace = T, prob = c(0.55,0.45))
)
bird3.data <- data.frame( id =  rep(3,100),
                          colour = sample(c("Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green"), 100, replace=T, c(0.9, 0.02, 0.03, 0.05)),
                          size = sample(c("Large", "Medium","Small"), 100, replace = T, c(0.6,0.2, 0.2)),
                          texture = sample(c("Hard", "Soft"), 100, replace = T, prob = c(0.5,0.5))
)
bird4.data <- data.frame( id =  rep(4,200),
                          colour = sample(c("Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green"), 200, replace=T, c(0.4,0.3, 0.2, 0.1)),
                          size = sample(c("Large", "Medium","Small"), 200, replace = T, c(0.1,0.1, 0.8)),
                          texture = sample(c("Hard", "Soft"),200, replace = T, prob = c(0.3,0.7))
)
birds.data_c <- rbind(bird1.data ,bird2.data,bird3.data,bird4.data)# one frame to rule them all
birds.data <- birds.data_c[sample(nrow(birds.data_c)),] # and in the darkness shuffle them.
```

Comment: why do you throw out the interaction information? Is there no reason to assume that a bird might prefer small objects only if they are soft (just an example)? single-feature single-value preference is only one of many rules or heuristics bird behavior could be described by...

Comment: @jank, good point. The first reason is that I am not entirely sure how to do that. Second the data I have is going to get very sparse (in reality I have many birds and not a lot of observations per bird) if I analyse based on multiple features. Having said that, I would be very keen if you could demonstrate/explain how this can be done.

Comment: dataset size might indeed be a problem. Looking at single features is therefore not a bad idea (any more complex model might otherwise easily lead to overfitting). For exploratory purposes I would still try to look at the thre-dimensional (or at least the three two-dimensional) contingency tables (look at the proportions of objects chosen that share the same three (or two) features).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need variances covariances; I think you simply define a measure of selectivity. This could be any of various things - I don't know of a general agreement on this. Some ideas:

1. Max proportion - minimum proportion
2. Sum of absolute deviations from equal proportions
3. Just the maximum proportion
4. Any of these scaled by number of categories. One way to scale these would be to simulate random data, order the simulations by either 1) or 2) or 3) and then use the rank of the actual data. The simulation would only have to be done once, fortunately.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I tried combinations of these but had the feeling that I may be doing something haphazard / statistically invalid. Similar to 2, I looked at residuals as results of the $\chi^2$ tests (per feature) that I demonstrate in the question. But here the residuals compare the behaviour of `birdN` to the averages of the `rest`, as opposed to equal proportions (which I though were not representative of the 'default' bird behaviour). What do you think?

Comment: I think you need to compute the indices on each bird by itself, then compare. My 3 methods (or ranks of them) do this. Chi-square (as you note) doesn't. Also, mine are easy to understand, which I think is a plus :-). Why do you think they might be invalid?

Comment: I assumed this type of analysis would have a formal name (or as you say: "a general agreement" on how to proceed) and some literature on it, which I failed to find. Do you know of any application examples / papers online?

Comment: I don't know of any papers. I don't think that all analyses has to be "formal".